# Flex 3: Getting variables from URL

Tags: apache-flex, get, urlvariables

If I have an application located at http://sitename.com/myapp/ and i want to pass in a variable via the url (i.e. - http://sitename.com/myapp/?name=Joe), how can I get that name variable into a string var?

Comment: Did my answer help solve your problem? If so, you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark icon next to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the class Adobe provided [in this article](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_to_get_Query_String_in_Flex_Applications-17155.html).

```
  package 
  {
    import flash.external.*;
    import flash.utils.*;

    public class QueryString 
    {

      private var _queryString:String;
      private var _all:String;
      private var _params:Object;

      public function get queryString():String
      {
        return _queryString;
      }
      public function get url():String
      {
        return _all;
      }
      public function get parameters():Object
      {
        return _params;
      }           


      public function QueryString()
      {

        readQueryString();
      }

      private function readQueryString():void
      {
        _params = {};
        try 
        {
          _all = 
  ExternalInterface.call("window.location.href.toString");
          _queryString =
  ExternalInterface.call("window.location.search.substring", 1);
          if(_queryString)
          {

            var params:Array = _queryString.split('&');
            var length:uint = params.length;

            for (var i:uint=0,index:int=-1; i 0)
              {
                var key:String = kvPair.substring(0,index);
                var value:String = kvPair.substring(index+1);
                _params[key] = value;
              }
            }
          }
        }catch(e:Error) { trace("Some error occured.
  ExternalInterface doesn't work in Standalone player."); }
      }

    }
  }
```

**UPDATE:** An updated version of this class can also [be found here](http://www.flexer.info/2007/11/28/access-the-query-string-variables-from-flex-application/), although I haven't tried this one.

**UPDATE 2:**
Here's an example on how to use the Querystring class:

```
public function CheckForIDInQuerystring():void
{
  // sample URL: http://www.mysite.com/index.aspx?id=12345
  var qs:QueryString = new QueryString;

  if (qs.parameters.id != null)
  {   
    // URL contains the "id" parameter
    trace(qs.parameters.id);
  }
  else
  {                 
    // URL doesn't contain the "id" parameter
    trace("No id found.");
  }
}
```

Comment: could you post what i'd have to do to get this working?  I've tried following the examples on the links, but i couldn't get it.

Comment: @Brds I added a quick example on how to use the Querystring class I posted earlier. If my answer helps solve your issue, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark icon next to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Divide 'em with String.split() and conquer:

```
    var url:String = "http://www.xxx.zzz/myapp?arg1=vae&arg2=victus";
    var params:String = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("?") + 1);
    if (params.length == url.length) return; //no params
    for each (var pair:String in params.split("&"))
    {
        trace("Got parameter:");
        var nameValue:Array = pair.split("=");
        trace("name: " + nameValue[0] + ", value: " + nameValue[1]);
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> Got parameter:
> name: arg1, value: vae
> Got parameter:
> name: arg2, value: victus
> ```