# Getting an URL parameter value in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, url, parameters

I'm have the following URL :

```
www.example.com?arg1=foobar
```

I want to get the `arg1` value.
I tried to use the following code:

```
var bm:IBrowserManager;
bm= bm.getInstance();
browserManager.init();
var o:Object = URLUtil.stringToObject(bm.fragment, "&");
Alert.show(o.arg1);
```

It works with the following URL:

```
www.example.com#arg1=foobar
```

So it requires the `#` instead of the `?` .

How can get the parameter "arg1" from Flex (nicely) from URLs such as :

```
www.example.com?arg1=foobar
```

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075187/flex-3-getting-variables-from-url/6075431#6075431) a while ago.

I use the class Adobe provided [in this article](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_to_get_Query_String_in_Flex_Applications-17155.html). An updated version of this class can also [be found here](http://www.flexer.info/2007/11/28/access-the-query-string-variables-from-flex-application/), although I haven't tried this one.

```
  package 
  {
    import flash.external.*;
    import flash.utils.*;

    public class QueryString 
    {

      private var _queryString:String;
      private var _all:String;
      private var _params:Object;

      public function get queryString():String
      {
        return _queryString;
      }
      public function get url():String
      {
        return _all;
      }
      public function get parameters():Object
      {
        return _params;
      }           


      public function QueryString()
      {

        readQueryString();
      }

      private function readQueryString():void
      {
        _params = {};
        try 
        {
          _all = 
  ExternalInterface.call("window.location.href.toString");
          _queryString =
  ExternalInterface.call("window.location.search.substring", 1);
          if(_queryString)
          {

            var params:Array = _queryString.split('&');
            var length:uint = params.length;

            for (var i:uint=0,index:int=-1; i 0)
              {
                var key:String = kvPair.substring(0,index);
                var value:String = kvPair.substring(index+1);
                _params[key] = value;
              }
            }
          }
        }catch(e:Error) { trace("Some error occured.
  ExternalInterface doesn't work in Standalone player."); }
      }

    }
  }
```

Here's an example on how to use the Querystring class:

```
public function CheckForIDInQuerystring():void
{
  // sample URL: http://www.mysite.com/index.aspx?id=12345
  var qs:QueryString = new QueryString;

  if (qs.parameters.id != null)
  {   
    // URL contains the "id" parameter
    trace(qs.parameters.id);
  }
  else
  {                 
    // URL doesn't contain the "id" parameter
    trace("No id found.");
  }
}
```