# How do I use a question mark in Actionscript 2.0 with getURL function?

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, google-chrome, actionscript, geturl

Actionsctipt code:

```
on(press)
{
     getURL(escape("address.html?0"));
}
```

This works absolutely fine in Internet Explorer but in Chrome in the question mark is obviously made into "%3F".

Any ideas how I can stop this from happening and still keep it compatible with IE and other popular browsers?

Thanks.

Comment: wish it was that simple mgraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mgraph says in his comment, you shouldn't escape the entire URL, simply do:

```
getURL("address.html?0");
```

If your real URL (guessing "address.html?0" is a simplified example) has parts that needs to be escaped, then you would want to escape those parts only, to avoid having the ? and similar being escaped. So for example like this:

```
var userName:String = "Lars Blåsjö";
getURL("page.html?name=" + escape(userName));
```

Comment: I have tried all of this, it was the first things I thought of doing when I discovered the problem. If I do not escape the Qmark it leaves it out and anything following it (in Chrome), if escape it then it converts it as I previously said to "%3F".

Comment: It sounds very strange that not escaping would leave out the question mark. I have never experienced that, or had any problems with getURL() and such URLs, in any browser. How does your URL look exactly? Is it "address.html?0" or is that just an example?

Comment: it's literally just letters then ".html?0"

Comment: That works perfectly without escape() in all a browsers I currently have available for testing. So again, you shouldn't need to escape anything, simply do getURL("address.html?0")

Comment: I know for certain it works in Internet Explorer, just not in Chrome. Did you test Chrome too? Thanks for helping by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `Querystring` class provided by Adobe I used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075187/flex-3-getting-variables-from-url).

Comment: Isn't that a bit OTT for a compatibility issue? Is there not some simpler fix for this within the string?

Comment: @user1221906 I wouldn't consider it OTT if it fixes your issue, is compatible in all browsers and prevents you from having to escape special characters. It's a single class that can be easily reused throughout your app. I'm curious why you think that would be considered OTT?